# How to prevent a corrupted file from being rsynced to remote server and good/non-corrupted copy being on the destination deleted?

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync, restore

I am using this command:

```
rsync -avzh --delete --progress source folder remote folder
```

My source folder contains many video `*.mp4` files.

I want all the videos to be rsynced to a destination folder in a remote server quite frequently.

There is one video called `sample.mp4` which has been successfully rsynced.

But, `sample.mp4` file is somehow corrupted before the next rsync and I don't know it.

Now when rsync command has been executed, I guess what'll happen is:

- First, the previously copied `sample.mp4` in the remote server will be deleted.
- Then, the corrupted `sample.mp4` in source folder will be regarded as a new file and rsynced to remote server.
- So I will have a corrupted file but I still think it is a perfect copy for future restore.

What can I do to prevent such a thing?

Comment: Rsync simply copies files. It doesn’t do data integrity checks that say “Hey, this source is damaged but the destination is fine; let me skip it.” What you might be looking for is backup solution that has snapshot capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `rsync` with `--backup` (and possibly `--suffix` or `--backup-dir`) it will make a backup of the existing file.

It also depends how you tell `rsync` to detect changed files on the source.

- If `rsync` uses the default "quick check" (size and time) the corrupted file may not be copied over since the corruption may not change the size or date (this of course depends on what caused the corruption), in which case your backup copy will remain correct.
- If `rsync` use the `--checksum` then the file will be copied (but you will get a backup version)

If you usually don't modify the video files, using `--backup` and then immediately checking for backed up files at the destination would be a good way to 1) be warned about corrupted files and 2) restore the correct version before it is clobbered by the next backup.